# load balancer not reachable after creating as service

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have deployed simple app -NGINX and a Load balancer service in Kubernetes.
I can see that pods are running as well as service but calling Loadbalancer external IP is givings server error -site can't be reached .Any suggestion please

**app.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**Service.Yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: nginx-service
spec:
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
 - port: 80
 selector:
 app: nginx
```

[image]
P.S. -Attached outcome from terminal.

Comment: Are you using Minikube ?

Comment: No,in Azure.i made other application and it works, not sure .I will paste the solution as well.Thanks

Comment: Oh okay cool. please add two spaces in the yaml. If my answer helped please leave an upvote. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Minikube to access the service then you might need to run one extra command. But if this is on a cloud provider then you have an error in your service file.

Please ensure that you put two space in yaml file but your indentation of the yaml file is messed up as you have only added 1 space. Also you made a mistake in the last line of `service.yaml` file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
   app: nginx
```